# Hide Firefox tab bar with hotkey?

Tags: firefox

I know this can be done via the `userChrome.css` file, I have been using that solution so far but its not sufficient for my needs, I’ve even tried it with a mouse hover and its been disappointing too.
I really need a way to toggle it at will. FF apparently used to allow this.
Any ideas or suggestions on how I can go about this would be much appreciated.

Running on V 84.0.1 (64-bit)
Win 10

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of Firefox you are using.

Comment: F11 will toggle fullscreen, is that what you mean by hide the tab bar?

Comment: No, being able to hide it at any window size, thanks though